# Is there a better permalink solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a website in C# and ASP.NET MVC where people can manage their own web pages. At the moment I am using the permalink solution of StackOverflow but I am not sure if this will work in my situation because people will add and delete pages constantly. This means that the id in the pages table will grow very large.

Example: mydomain.com/page/**17745288223**/my-page-title

Is there a better solution?

Comment: And why is that a problem? How large will it actually grow? Are you expecting more than a few million pages (that's 7 characters). Are you expecting more than a few billion pages (that's 9 - 10 characters)..

Comment: If people add new pages once per second, it will take *562.326* years to reach *17745288223* pages.  Are you sure this is a real problem?  Even if it is, in that time range, is it YOUR problem? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that for your case (users creating pages) it's actually more user friendly to put all pages created by a single user under his/her own path i.e.:

```
 mydomain.com/page/{username/nickname/some-name-selected-by-user}/my-page-title
```

If you don't want to use such format an `int` or `long` in URL will probably do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use some kind of a hash to make lookups more efficient.  You could, for instance compute a SHA-1 hash of page title, creating date, user information, etc. - just like git does for commit ids.

Or you could use simple numbers, but convert them into some compact representation using hexadecimal numbers or alphanumerical characters like some url-shortening services.

Answer (score 0):

> This means that the id in the pages table will grow very large.

What's the problem with that?

The largest value for an `int` is also very large (just over 2 billion) so I doubt it will hit any limit unless you are planning to have millions of users with thousands of pages each.

If you are still worried then you can use a `long` (64-bit integer). It can handle trillions of users with millions of pages each. Note that the population of the Earth is only a few billion.

Answer (score 0):

Though this started as a comment I decided it was growing larger so here it is again..

The page id solution seems just fine.

What are you worried about? If you are expecting a few million pages that's 7 characters. If you are expecting more than a few billion pages that's 9 - 10 characters.. Pretty manageable, I think.

You could also represent it as hex and reduce it to a maximum of 8 characters to fit up to 2^32 different ids.